# JavaFX pass value into instance of view, without using static setter

Tags: java, javafx

I'm starting a JavaFX view from my main class, and I want to pass in a value to that instance of the view. Currently I'm using a static member variable in the View class, but I'd like to avoid statics if possible.

**Main Class**

```
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int value = 3;
        View.setValue(value);
        Application.launch(new View().getClass());
    }
}
```

**View Class**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class View extends Application
{

    private static int value;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public static void setValue(int valueIn)
    {
        View.value = valueIn;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this, that avoids using static member variables or creating a launch() method in the view class that has a parameter for value?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Just to clarify as I omitted from the original post (my bad I know), the actual "value" I will be wanting to pass in is an instance of an MBassador event bus (i.e. MBassador bus), otherwise all your answers would have worked perfectly

Comment: You can't: you can't get a reference to the instance of the `Application` subclass created by the launch method, other than from within that instance itself. What you're trying to do really doesn't make much sense: in a JavaFX application, you should consider the `start()` method - **not** the `main()` method - as the entry point to the application. (A JavaFX Application doesn't even need a `main()` method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a better way is to provide your value as argument of your program then get it from the start method as next:

```
public class View extends Application {

    private int value;

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        List<String> unnamedParams = getParameters().getUnnamed();
        if (unnamedParams.size() > 0) {
            this.value = Integer.parseInt(unnamedParams.get(0));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("No argument has been provided");
        }
    }
```

Then your `Main` class would be:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(new View().getClass(), args);
    }
}
```

Finally launch your program with your argument as next:

```
java Main 2
```

If you don't want to provide it as parameter to your java program then put it
int the main method using `Application.launch(new View().getClass(), "2");`

**Response Update**

What you want to achieve cannot be done properly as we have no way to interfere in how JavaFX creates your `Application`, the only things that we can provide are String arguments as explained above.

Your approach is a good workaround but if you only need to launch one single application if not you could also use a `ThreadLocal` to store your object temporary until you get it from the `init` method since it is the only method called by the calling thread.

```
public class Main
{
    private static final ThreadLocal<MBassador> THREAD_LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        THREAD_LOCAL.set(myObject)
        try {
            Application.launch(new View().getClass(), args);
        } finally {
            THREAD_LOCAL.remove();
        }
    }

    public static MBassador getMBassador() {
        return THREAD_LOCAL.get();
    }
}
```

Then you can get it from your Application in the init method as next:

```
@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    MBassador obj = Main.getMBassador();
    ...
}
```

Comment: How would you recommend doing this if I wanted to pass in an argument that won't be parsed nicely from a string? I'm thinking of something like MBassador<AbstractMessage>, which unfortunately doesn't have a nice .parseX() method associated with it.

Comment: I don't know your class, maybe you could provide it as String in JSON format? or only provide the arguments to create the instance of this object

Comment: Again, as in my comment below the question, the way to do this is to move the initialization directly to the `start()` method. Don't initialize things in `main()`.

Comment: For reference, MBassador is an event bus, I can't create an instance of the bus in the view as it has to be the same one  as used in the main (the main also passes the instance into other classes). JSON I believe would not work for the same reason

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that "value" is not actually the type of thing I want to pass in

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Again, move the initialization to `start()`. If you are passing the thing you are initializing to other classes, pass it to those other classes from `start()`, not from `main()` (create another thread if you need). The `start()` method *is a replacement for the `main` method*.

Comment: I don't know whether this has any bearing on what you just said, but I have a main class, that kicks off the view and also the controller/model I'm using a MVC pattern). Am I correct in thinking that there should be no main() in the main class? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

From manual:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html

> Typical usage is:
>
> ```
>  public static void main(String[] args) {
>      Application.launch(MyApp.class, args);
>  }
> ```

You should not create Application by yourself. `Application.launch` will create the object of given class and then starts it.
You can simply pass the arguments by `args` and then access them in your application class with `getParameters()`.